# how to insert fuse module into linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, fuse

my os is centos

kernel is 2.6.18-92.1.17.el5xen.

fuse version is fuse-2.7.4
I compiled it like this：

```
    ./configure --enable-kernel-module --with-kernel=/usr/src/linux
     make &&　make install
```

then "modprobe fuse",but it warned like this:

```
     FATAL: Error inserting fuse (/lib/modules/2.6.18-92.1.17.el5xen/kernel/fs/fuse/fuse.ko): Operation not permitted
```

but I did it as root.

and another way to install it :

```
      /sbin/insmod ./kernel/fuse.ko
```

and i got :

```
    insmod: error inserting './kernel/fuse.ko': -1 Invalid module format
```

is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: You need root privileges to insert modules using insmod. And as the second error says, it means your fuse.ko is invalid. Also take a look at the dmesg logs to get more details about the error thrown by the kernel.

Comment: i did do it as root.And after doing that,dmesg gave me such a message:"ksign: module signed with unknown public key
- signature keyid: 5ca5e7aec7491d45 ver=3".    What does that mean?